# Grails database-migration - dbm-gorm-diff confusion

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I just installed the database-migration plugin for a Grails 1.3.7 application that already contains about 100 domains.  I ran the initial dbm-generate-gorm-changelog which generated a changelog.groovy that looks alright.

I added a single domain with 3 properties and then ran:

dbm-gorm-diff testing.groovy

What I expected was a changelog that would create my new domain.  What I got was a changelog with 1260 lines of changeSets.  Now, it does contain my new domain.  But it also contains most (not all) of my other domains, which didn't change in the 60 seconds between scripts.  Am I understanding how this works incorrectly?  Or am I running the wrong command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to "run" the first migration to get it into the Liquibase table, so when you run a second it does a diff. You just generated two independent files.

See "Typical initial workflow" at http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-database-migration/docs/manual/guide/2%20Getting%20Started.html